# TypeError: req.next is not a function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I cannot seem to figure out this issue, it literally just started happening, no code changed!

```
TypeError: req.next is not a function
```

The code is failing on line **120**. Here is the corresponding sql query, as well as line **120**

```
// Setup form response endpoint
router.get('/form_submit', function (req, res, next) {
    var parentFirstName = req.query.employee_First_name
    var parentLastName = req.query.employee_last_name
    var parentEmail = req.query.employee_email_address
    childFirstName = req.query.Child_name
    childLastName = req.query.Child_last_name
    var relations = req.query.relations
    var number = req.query.phone_number
    var allergies = req.query.Allergies
    var restrictions = req.query.Dietary_Restrictions
      
    const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
    var queryw = "SELECT * from table"
    var numrows = 0
    ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(queryw, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(data);
            numrows = data.length
            conn.close(function () {
                console.log("DOING COUNT:");
                var crypto = require("crypto");
                var id = crypto.randomBytes(3).toString('hex');
                console.log(id)
                var realIndex = id
      
                var permission = req.query.permission;
                console.log(permission)
    
                if (permission == null || permission == " " + undefined || permission == " undefined" || permission == undefined) {
                    permission = "No"
                    console.log("inside permission")
                }
    
                if (numrows <= 5) {
                    var query2="insert into table (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CHILD_FIRST_NAME, CHILD_LAST_NAME, RELATIONSHIP_CHILD, CONTACT_CELLNUMBER, ALLERGIES, DIETARY_RESTRICTIONS, STATUS, EMAIL, PERMISSION, REALINDEX) Values ('" + parentFirstName + "', '" + parentLastName + "', '" + childFirstName + "', '" + childLastName + "', '" + relations +"', '" + number + "', '" + allergies + "', '" + restrictions + "', 'ACTIVE', '" + parentEmail + "', '" + permission + "', '" + realIndex + "')"
                    console.log(req.body.permission)
                    ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                        conn.query(query2, function (err, data) {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            else console.log(data);
                            conn.close(function () {
                                console.log(numrows);
                                const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
                                res.render('done', { title: 'Express', user });
                                console.log(query2);
                                res.render('done');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                } 
                else if (numrows > 5) {
                    console.log('CALLNG WAITLIST')
                    var query3="insert into table (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CHILD_FIRST_NAME, CHILD_LAST_NAME, RELATIONSHIP_CHILD, CONTACT_CELLNUMBER, ALLERGIES, DIETARY_RESTRICTIONS, STATUS, EMAIL, PERMISSION, REALINDEX) Values ('" + parentFirstName + "', '" + parentLastName + "', '" + childFirstName + "', '" + childLastName + "', '" + relations +"', '" + number + "', '" + allergies + "', '" + restrictions + "', 'WAITLIST',  '" + parentEmail + "', '" + permission + "', '" + realIndex + "')"
                    ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function (err, conn) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                        conn.query(query3, function (err, data) {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            else console.log(data);
                            conn.close(function () {
                                console.log("GOING INTO ELSE STATEMENT");
                                console.log("THIS IS THE NUMROW COUNT", numrows)
                            });
                            const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
                            console.log(user)
                            res.render('done', { title: 'done', user: user });
                        });
                    });
                }  
            }); 
        });
    });
      
    console.log('Attempting to send email')
    try {
        // Read more here for Message Options https://nodemailer.com/message/
        // Please change these to your email
        const user = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
        const message = {
            from: "my email", // <= should be verified and accepted by service provider. ex. 'youremail@'
              to: req.query.employee_email_address, //
              subject: "Registration for " + user.firstName, // <= email subject ex. 'Test email' var parentFirstName = req.query.employee_First_name
              text: "Thank you " + user.firstName + " " + user.lastName + " for registering for ",
        };
    
        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).send(`Failed to Send Email: ${error}`)
            }
            console.log(`Successfully Sent Email ${info.messageId}`)
            res.status(200).send(`Successfully Sent Email ${info.messageId}`)
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`We failed to send Email: ${error}`)
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
    JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user)
    res.render('done', { title: 'Express', user });  
})
```

Line 120: `res.render('done', { title: 'done', user: user });`
Why is this happening?

I am not sure what is going wrong. It literally just stopped working. No code changes, nothing.
And yes, I know my code is subject to sql injection. It is being fixed

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code?

Comment: @zx01 just provided the whole function.

Comment: I don't know what is causing this but from your code it has two obvious problems, One is that you are opening a database connection for each request instead of using one, second is that you are executing `render` two times.

Answer (score 0):

I find multiple errors here.

- You can only perform res.send/res.render once in the same request.
- If you need to use both, you must clearly differentiate for what type of request you will return JSON, html, etc, (and call send or render only once)
- I think you should read about asynchronous programming, since in this case you are invoking functions that will be executed asynchronously and it may be that you execute res.render when the response has already been sent.